# Showing product attributes at checkout

Tags: nopcommerce

This has got to be an obvious answer, but I can't seem to find it. I have some shirts that I'm selling using nopCommerce and I included a product attribute called "Size", with values of "small", "medium", "large". It works fine. But the problem is, when I view my orders, how do I know which size they ordered? I can't seem to find it anywhere on the order screen. In fact, on the order screen, I don't see anything about attributes at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the admin section, go to Sales -> Orders -> view the order -> Products tab, the products and attributes will be listed.

[image]

Comment: Mine doesn't have that. It just lists the product name, price, quantity, discount and total. I posted a screen shot here: http://i.imgur.com/HxTrsvX.jpg

Comment: I have another screen shot too that shows the sizes during check out, but no matter what size I choose, I can never see it during the order checkout screen: http://imgur.com/UrAjOCW

Comment: That comes from the OrderProductVariant.AttributeDescription field.  Do you know how to query the database to see if that is populated?

Comment: Yes. In the database, I queried the OrderItem table and on one of the orders, there is an AttributeDescription field that contains "Size: XXL" and when I view that order in the software, I do see it. For some reason though, its only on that one order. Any ideas?

Comment: Do the ones that don't have the info have the same ProductId as the one where you see Size: XXL?